# Sphinx mac osx Lion with zendServer

Tags: mysql, macos, sphinx, zend-server

The follow issue I have.

I try to install Sphinx on my Mac OS X Lion but it fails by the command 'make'.
The './configure' looks to work well, I get the message 'Thank you for choosing Sphinx!'. After I want to run the command 'Make' it goes wrong.

for './configre' i tried also './configure --with-mysql=/usr/local/zend/mysql' because I think the problem of the error comes from I the fact that I don't use mac's mysql but I use zendServer.

```
MacBook-Pro-van-nick:sphinxsearch nick$ make
Making all in src
/bin/sh svnxrev.sh ..
make  all-am
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config  -DSYSCONFDIR="\"/usr/local/etc\"" -DDATADIR="\"/usr/local/var/data\"" -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/zend/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch i386 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL   -Wall -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MT sphinx.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sphinx.Tpo -c -o sphinx.o sphinx.cpp
In file included from sphinx.cpp:16:
sphinx.h:64:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory

// More errro's here of course as a consequence from the one above (I guess)
```

Thanks in advance.

With kind regards,

Nick

Comment: This problem is fixed by installing the mysql package from 'http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4006'. add the attrib mysql includes to your ./configure install command with the path tho the includes and it will work well.